# Programmatically submit Aurelia form that uses submit.delegate=save()

Tags: javascript, form-submit, dispatchevent, aurelia

I have a form which (obviously) has a `submit.delegate` attribute pointing to my VM's `save()` method.

I'm now building a separate custom attribute from where I'd like to programmatically be able to submit any form.

Basically this: `<form submit.delegate="save()" custom-attribute-here>`

And then inside my custom attribute's JS class I'd like to be able to: `this.el.submit()` in which case the form's `submit.delegate` method should be called.

I first tried with `this.el.submit()` which didn't work in either Chrome or Firefox, but using `this.el.dispatchEvent(new Event('submit', {bubbles: true}))` actually does work in Chrome. Firefox still submits the form "normally" and ignores the method in the `submit.delegate` attribute.

Is there a solution to this problem that works in all browsers?

Comment: Do you need to actually submit the form, or only ever run the function bound to `submit.delegate"?

Comment: I want to run the function, but from my custom attribute I have no way of knowing whether the form even has one bound at all. I'd like my custom attribute to work regardless that's why I figured triggering the form's native submit event would work in all cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While not ideal, triggering the `[type=submit]` element's `click` event works:

`this.form.querySelector('[type=submit]').click()`

Answer (score 0):

I've created customAttribute for this. Using this customAttribute you can call `sumbit.delegate` outside `form` tag.

To Use it

1. create a reference to `form` tag by using [ref](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/binding/latest/binding-basics/5), `<form role="form" ref="form" submit.delegate="saveEmployee(employee)">`.
2. Second use single value binding, see more info [here](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/templating/latest/templating-custom-attributes/4), outside `form` tag `<button class="btn btn-primary" submit-form.bind="form">Save</button>`.

Code is in Typescript. add this class as [globalResources](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/templating/latest/templating-html-behaviors-introduction/5).

```
import { DOM } from 'aurelia-pal';

export class SubmitFormCustomAttribute {
    /**
     * Form element.
     */
    value: Element;
    formSubmitListener = event => {
        this.dispatchFormSubmit(this.value);
    };

    static inject = [Element];
    constructor(private element: Element) { }

    bind() {
        this.element.addEventListener('click', this.formSubmitListener);
    }

    unbind() {
        this.element.removeEventListener('click', this.formSubmitListener);
    }

    dispatchFormSubmit(form: Element) {
        const submitEvent = DOM.createCustomEvent('submit', {
            bubbles: true
        });
        submitEvent.preventDefault();
        form.dispatchEvent(submitEvent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Seeing as you're using `dispatchEvent` I'm surprised you don't get the same issues as I did? Have you tested your code in Firefox?

Comment: Hi @powerbuoy update my answer to work with FF. Calling `preventDefault()` will not cause page load.

Comment: Alright, so `preventDefault()` is the solution then (no need for the custom attribute really seeing as I'm creating my _own_ custom attribute). Are you sure `preventDefault()` has no side effects?

Comment: I don't think so, I've seen it on Listener code in aurelia templating when using trigger.